# What are the equivalent bash cli commands for this graphical actions?

Tags: sound, kde, sip, phonon

I have a problem with the audio system and sip clients (all of them)

If I switch off and on Phonon from the kde graphical UI then for some time the audio works fine again
[image]

Refering to the picture, what I do is change *Profilo* from the value *Duplex Stereo Analogico* to the value *Off*, then I Aplly changes, and then again I set back *Profilo* to
*Duplex Stereo Analogico* and Apply changes

I would like to know what are the equivalent bash cli commands for this graphical actions.
So that I can write a script that would me much faster and easier to me.

Comment: Maybe `pulseaudio -k` will help?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there aren't any implemented commands to control Phonon from command line.There is a request on the KDE Bug Tracker:

http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212091
(Bug 212091 - Configure phonon from command line)

It seems it's not yet implemented until now.

Phonon page links:
http://phonon.kde.org and http://userbase.kde.org/Phonon

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is a `pulseaudio` setting:

1. Check for available cards & profiles

   ```
   pactl list cards
   ```
2. Use this command to change profile

   ```
   pactl [options] set-card-profile  CARD PROFILE
   ```

Reference:

`pactl -h` & [`man pactl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pactl.1.html)